# Java-8 Thread in Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I create this piece of code :

```
static int i;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            hello(i);
        }).start();
    }

}

public static void hello(int i) {
    System.out.println("Thread number = " + i);
}
```

When you look at this you think it will print :

```
Thread number = 1
Thread number = 2
Thread number = 3
Thread number = 4
Thread number = 5
```

But this is not correct it print a random int and the illogical it print `6` sometimes like :

```
Thread number = 5
Thread number = 6
Thread number = 6
Thread number = 6
Thread number = 6
```

I add `Thread.sleep(2000);` after :

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        hello(i);
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

And it show me a correct result:

```
Thread number = 1
Thread number = 2
Thread number = 3
Thread number = 4
Thread number = 5
```

> Why it show me that result in the first one and it show me 6, and in fact the 6 is not exist? and why it not print ordered int 1,2,3,...? Any explanation about that?

Comment: Why illogical? The loop runs for `i == 5` and increments it to `6`.Only then it breaks from the loop because you are using `<=`. The main thread is so fast in the loop, that the newly created threads only see `i` as `6` without sleeping the main thread within the loop.

Comment: In .Net this is considered access to a modified closure and can be resolved by adding a temporary variable set to i and passing that to the thread. I assume it would work the same in Java. `for (...) { int temp = i; new Thread(... hello(temp)...).start();} `

Comment: yes @jlordo i understand now, my bad i really forgot this point, thank you!

Comment: You are printing `i` at the time the code is run, not a copy of the value at the time the loop iterates.

Comment: "in fact the 6 is not exist?" If `i== 6` didn't exist, your loop wouldn't stop.

Comment: `When you look at this you think it will print :` I certainly don't. You've got 1 variable, which can only have 1 value at a time.

Comment: What’s the point of starting multiple threads and expecting single-threaded behavior?

Comment: i just want to test the thread in a loop @Holger just curious that's all

Comment: There is no “thread in a loop”, you are only *starting* them in a loop. If you don’t understand that threads are independent from your local control structure, you are most likely not ready to use multiple threads. What do you think, what threads are?

Comment: mmm, thank you @Holger for the lesson so i will not use threads in loop again

Comment: There is nothing wrong with starting threads in a loop, as long as you don’t expect them to behave like code in loop (in other words, like not being *threads*). As hinted, think about, what the actual difference between non-threaded code and code using multiple threads is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the time the `Thread` executes the `Runnable's` `run` method the loop might already finish it's execution and the last value `i` took is `6`, remember that you are doing `i<=5` which means when the loop finish's `i` will equal `6`.

Answer (score 2):

What you got is completely logic output, and you might get even more odd print outputs. As [the javadoc of the *start* method in **Thread**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) says:

> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

The time when `sub Thread` started in the loop will execute is non-determinist, the result you got shows that *1 Thread* executed before the loop thread finishing its last loop and *4 others* executed after the entire loop finished.

The reason you got the order you expected after adding `Thread.sleep(2000);` in the loop is only because you give each `sub Thread` enough time to execute in real practice, that's all. The execution order is non-determinist essentially/theoretically.

Answer (score -1):

if as in other language, Your thread code is scheduled in a non-determinist way, so at time of running the threading code will access the var i taking ACTUAL value.

I rewrote a bit cleaner code:

public class Main  {

static int i=0;

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception
{
    // Lambda Runnable
    Runnable task = () -> {
        hello(i);
    };

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

}

```
public static void hello(int i) {
    System.out.println("Thread number = " + i);
}
```

}

note I have to set "i" to static..

A Cleaner solution will be to use a Thread-derived class with its "i" and set it in constructor, so every thread instance of subclass will have its own value..